# A thrust problem: How can I copy a host_vector to device_vector with a customized permutation order?

Tags: c++, gpu, thrust

I have an array in host, and I want to transfer it to device with a different order.

I have tried this toy code complied with `nvc++ test.cpp -stdpar`

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <array>

using Real = float;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        std::array<std::size_t,6> idx{0,1,2,3,5,4};


        thrust::host_vector<Real> hvec(6);

        thrust::sequence(hvec.begin(),hvec.end());

        typedef thrust::host_vector<Real>::iterator EleItor;
        typedef std::array<std::size_t,6>::iterator IdxItor;

        thrust::permutation_iterator<EleItor,IdxItor> itor(hvec.begin(),idx.begin());

        thrust::device_vector<Real> test;
        thrust::copy(itor,itor+6,test);  // error
        thrust::copy(itor,itor+6,std::ostream_iterator<Real>(std::cout," ");  

}
```

The problem is that `thrust::copy` does not allow copy from host to device, how can I bypass this restriction?

Comment: Putting this code into a `.cpp` file and then using `nvc++ -stdpar` without using the actual `std::` algorithms is hacky and has the disadvantage of transforming (almost) all heap allocations into CUDA managed allocations which can be very bad for performance. The correct way of explicitly using Thrust with `nvc++` is putting the code into a `.cu` file.

Comment: For less boilerplate I also recommend using `auto` and the iterator factory functions, i.e. `auto itor = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(hvec.begin(), idx.begin());` and get rid of the `typedef`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/) is is possible to use `thrust::copy` to copy from host to device, but you need to pass the device **iterator**:

```cpp
//-----------------------------vvvvvvvv--
thrust::copy(itor, itor+6, test.begin());
```

Note that before that you need to allocate memory for the device vector.
Fortunately the `thrust::device_vector` has a constructor taking a size that will allocate the required memory.
You can use something like:

```cpp
thrust::device_vector<Real> test(host_vector.size());
```

---

Edit (credit goes to @paleonix):
There is another constructor taking iterators, i.e. one can do both allocation and copy as initialization in one line which also has the advantage of avoiding the unnecessary initialization of the memory to `0.0f`.

```cpp
thrust::device_vector<Real> test(itor, itor+6);
```

Comment: I forget the `.begin()` It is a careless mistake. I don't think this question would be useful to the community, I shall delete it later...

Comment: @batman216 please consider to keep it. Beginners who struggle with thrust can make use of it (with my answer). BTW - there also the issue of the allocation (in addition to the iterator).

Comment: @batman216 I added an optimization that also might be interesting for many beginners.